# Google Cloud Error: ERROR: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, raspberry-pi4

I'm making a voice recognition program, but I can't seem to be able to send a request to the Cloud. Whenever I try:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [PROJECT_ID] --member "serviceAccount:[SEVICE-ACCOUNT-NAME]@[PROJECT_ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role "roles/owner"
```

I get this:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding#EXAMPLES), you should write the command like:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding YOUR_PROJECT_ID --member "serviceAccount:NAME@YOUR_PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role "roles/owner"
```

This should work for you!

Comment: I was actually looking for something like: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

Comment: Keep in mind that if you follow this quickstart, you should remove the symbol "[" and "]" when writing the command.
This would be something like:

`gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding YOUR_PROJECT_ID --member "serviceAccount:NAME@YOUR_PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role "roles/owner"`

Comment: This isn't for a service account!

Comment: This was it for me. Seems like in this page: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/create-environments#gcloud_2
there is a typo in that the first parameter which had me putting in the service account instead of the project id. It should be like this answer says!

Answer (score 0):

It can be an issue of currently active environment config.

Please check it:

gcloud config configurations list

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a wrong parameter as the output suggests.

Make sure you use the correct parameters as ericcco suggests.
The project id  is typically something like my-project-3473646 .

The command would then be something like:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project-3473646 --member "serviceAccount:SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME@my-project-3473646.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role "roles/owner"
```

It helps if you upvote or mark as solved, it will help others, thank you.